# How to best name enterprise tools or portals?

Tags: terminology, information-architecture, labels, enterprise, branding

If you have worked within a large organisation you would have most probably operated in highly siloed environments with a lot of legacy systems and third party software. I have worked in a number of big organisation as an information architect and I am struck by one practice in particular, namely how departments create names for their internal products, tools or portals of which there is of course plenty!

There is of course the excessive use of acronyms to describe software but there are also product names that fail at describing what any given piece of software does. As an example; a simple exercise intended to get access / permission to use a portal or a tool becomes extremely  difficult without knowing exactly the name of the product or tool which is a big findability issue. So my question is :

1. Is there any resource or guidance for naming enterprise tools or
   portals?
2. What advice / guidance best practices would you suggest?

Comment: Have you considered setting a naming convention? Sounds like the wording wouldn't matter as much if the convention is followed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good article about branding and labeling intranets:

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/branding-intranet/

> By far, the most common names for intranets I have encountered are:
>       •   Intranet
>       •   Portal
>       •   Inside 
>       •    Hub
>   These names may seem unimaginative, but in practice they work quite well.
>
> •   Identity: The name conveys the intranet’s goal and identity. An intranet called Center, for example, can suggest to employees that it is the place where everyone congregates and gets information. An intranet called Harmony could indicate that groups recently merged or acquired will be working together.
>
> •   Reference: Employees use the name of the intranet to refer to it in speech and writing. The name should be easy to remember, spell, and pronounce. Employees should never wonder how to say the name of the intranet and they should not be embarrassed or shy about saying it.